# What are these [size=40] tags in orientdb

Tags: java, api, graph, orientdb, nosql

I have been working on a project and I have made 215 edges originating from a single vertex toward a different vertices of a different class however when I use Java API (Graph API) to get edges it comes to 40 only. Please help [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvdpO.png)

Comment: Hi, so you have two vertices (A and B) connected with 215 edges b/w them, is it right?
Could you add the results of `select out("Contribute").size() from #A` ; `select in("Contribute").size() from #B` ; `select * from contribute where out = #A and in =#B`

Comment: Actually to be precise I have 215 edges originating from a single vertex to different vertices of a class. So I tried to get the all the edges through the iterator but it doesn't return all of them.

`for(Edge contributeEdge:userNode.getEdges(Direction.OUT,"@class","Contribute")){  //Code }`

Comment: Which release? I remember a non recent version had this problem. Please use a recent OrientDB version.

Comment: OrientDB Server v2.1.17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I have figured the solution for this problem. Basically I had 2 loops first one for iterating towards the vertices and the second one to make several edges for each vertices. Now I was using `graph.commit()` after every edge insertion earlier. Now I decided to commit after every vertex is done, that is I reduced the commit frequency from n^2 to n. This solved the problem and I has able to add and retrieve all the edges.

Answer (score 2):

Size[40] means that the vertex #16:633 has 40 outgoing edges Contribute

Comment: I am afraid this not the case here as I queried the database and found out that 221 edges are there in the database. I searched for the user's RID against the out property of edge 'Contributes' It showed me 221 edges then why only 40 is showing there?

Comment: Could you post the result of this query: select out("Contribute").size() from #16:633

Comment: It's coming out 40 sir! but `select * from contribute where out = 16:633` gives 221 rows

Comment: Hi @Abhimanyu, have you done some delete operations ? If yes, what commands have you used ?

Comment: Sir I haven't done any delete operations , but when I refresh I execute 

`try{
     graph.dropEdgeType("Contribute");
    }catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
    System.out.println("=============Contribute deleted=========");`

This drops all the classes so deletes everything. That's all I use

Comment: dropEdgeType IS a delete operation

Comment: So is that a problem sir? Also I have made the question more elaborate you can have a look !